# Evaluation of integral containing exponentials and cube root of sine function.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, exponential-function

The original integral was $$\int_{-\ln{2}}^{\ln{2}} \frac{(\sin{x} +x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^x} \text{d}x$$
one can transform this with properties of definite integrals $(u = a + b - x)$ into $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\ln{2}}^{\ln{2}} \frac{(\sin{x}+x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^x}-\frac{(\sin{x}+x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^{-x}} \text{d}x$$ which is then able to be transformed into the much more approachable looking $$-2\int_{0}^{\ln{2}} (\sin{x}+x)^\frac{1}{3}\cdot \sinh{x} \text{d}x$$ but unfortunately I am unsure where to proceed from here. Help would be appreciated!

Edit: I've flagged my post as duplicate. See [Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\ln 2}^{\ln 2} e^{-x}(\sin x+x)^{1/3}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816820/evaluating-the-integral-int-ln-2-ln-2-e-x-sin-xx1-3dx). Thank you to John Omielan for the help!

Comment: Are you sure about the first formula $\int _{\ln 2}^{\ln 2}..$ ?

Comment: $$\int_{\ln{2}}^{\ln{2}} \frac{(\sin{x} +x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{e^x} \text{d}x
=0$$

Comment: I am in fact not sure, my fault! Changed bound from ln(2) to -ln(2).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\ln 2}^{\ln 2} e^{-x}(\sin x+x)^{1/3}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816820/evaluating-the-integral-int-ln-2-ln-2-e-x-sin-xx1-3dx) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B-%5Cln%7B2%7D%7D%5E%7B%5Cln%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B(%5Csin%7Bx%7D%20%2Bx)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D%7D%7Be%5Ex%7Ddx%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cln%7B2%7D%7D(%5Csin%7Bx%7D%2Bx)%5E%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%5Csinh%7Bx%7Ddx%24&p=1).

Comment: It does! I'm sorry, I looked for duplicates but didn't see any. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

If the question is well formulated, note that is trivial. You are integrating a continuous function between $a$ and $b$ with $a=\ln 2=b$. Since the two bounds are the same, the integral is zero.

Comment: Hi! Thank you but I definitely messed up the bounds.